# Trigger an event that triggers on scroll only on page load

Tags: jquery

I want to trigger a function that only trigger on scroll, is that possible?

```
$(document).ready(function() 
    $(document).scroll(function() {
        // do something here
    });

    // here I want to trigger the scroll function (without scrolling)
});
```

**I tried `$(document).scroll();` without success:**

```
$(document).ready(function() 
    $(document).scroll(function() {
        // do something here
    });
    $(document).scroll();
});
```

Comment: You want the browser to **literally** scroll, or you want to execute the code that **would execute** if the browser were scrolled?

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud The latter.

Comment: @Daan, try binding the handler to `window` instead of `document`. IIRC, `scroll` events cannot be triggered on the document.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi That's false and binding scroll on the document makes it work on tablets aswell.

Answer (score 2):

Change it to use a named function:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
    $(document).scroll(onScroll);

    onScroll();
});

function onScroll() {
}
```

Now that the function is named you can freely execute that code whenever you want.